# Nested loop changing multiple values while doing Boolean matrix multiplication

Tags: python, matrix, boolean, matrix-multiplication

Write a function that multiplies two matrices (A,B) and returns the results.  Both A and B are 2d lists and are of compatible dimensions for multiplication
My code converts 0 and 1 to true and false then multiplies them together, and then converts it back.

```
def matrix_multiply_boolean(A,B):
    #converts to boolean
    ra = len(A)
    ca = len(A[0])
    rb = len(B)
    cb = len(B[0])
    for i in range(ra):
        for z in range(ca):
           # print (A[i][z])
            if A[i][z]==0:
                A[i][z]=False
            if A[i][z]==1:
                A[i][z]=True
    for i in range(rb):
        for z in range(cb):
            print (B[i][z])
            if B[i][z]==0:
                B[i][z]=False
            if B[i][z]==1:
                B[i][z]=True

    #print(A)
    #print(B)
            #compares True and False vlaues
            #cant figure out why when the function cycles throught the first z #it sets two valeus to true

    new_list = [[True] * cb] * ra

    for z in range(ra):
        for i in range(cb): # *****on the second loop around the value of two #elements change and I have no idea why*****
            value = False 
            for j in range(ca):
                value = value or A[z][j] and B[j][i]
                print (value,j) #shows the value and how many times its been #throgh the loop.  goes 3 times 
            new_list[z][i] = value   #changes the value in the list
            print("newlist ",new_list[z][i]) # shows the value that was set #from line 59
            print(new_list) # shows you the list at the end of one whole #calculation

            #converts funtion back to boolean numbers
    rnl = len(new_list)
    cnl = len(new_list[0])
    for i in range(rnl):
        for z in range(cnl):
            #print (new_list[i][z])
            if new_list[i][z]==False:
                new_list[i][z]=0
            if new_list[i][z]==True:
                new_list[i][z]=1


    return new_list

A= [ [0,1,1],[1,0,0]]
B= [ [1,0],[0,0],[0,1]]
print(matrix_multiply_boolean(A,B))
```

Im getting the correct Boolean value when the multiplication is done but it isn't being set correctly, and I can not figure out why. Whats happening is after one row is done and it goes to start a new row and it changes the value of [1,0](current row) and [0,0](previous row same column) when the next multiplication is done instead of just [1,0].  This only happens on the first element of the loop for some reason

Expected values [[0,1],[1,0]]
Actual values [[1, 0], [1,0]]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
new_list = [[True] * cb] * ra
```

to

```
new_list = [[True for j in range(0, cb)] for i in range(0, ra)]
```

and it outputs the desired result.

The objects stored in `new_list` are not just copies of each other but really are the same objects. With your example (where `cb == 2` and `ra == 2`) `new_list` looks like this internally:

```
[[A, B], [A, B]]
```

where `A` and `B` are each a boolean with the value `True`. Now when you change `A` `new_list` is changed in two places because they each refer to the same object `A`. The same is the case for `B`. The two lists stored in `new_list` would have been always the same with your code.